# Comment on a Facebook post Using Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

My code is this

```
    request_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/378389388847425_614638371889191/comments?access_token=user_access_token&message=wow"
    uri = URI.parse(request_url)       
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    response = http.request(request)
    body = response.body

    feed_list = JSON.parse(body)
```

It returns

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

and comment is not showing on post.When i have publish_stream permission in access_token.Please help me

Comment: Do you have `publish_stream` permissions?

Comment: yes, i Have publish_stream permissions

Comment: It looks like you are sending a `GET` request instead of a `POST`. Can you add the code that actually sends the request?

Comment: i am putting all the code in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a `GET` request instead of a `POST`, so what you are getting is an empty list of existing comments. Try changing `Net::HTTP::Get` to `Net::HTTP::Post`.